# in_groups_of with fields_for in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've some fields in a form that I want to group by series of 3. Right now it looks like this

```
<!-- Variant boxes -->
<div class="row form-group">
  <%= f.fields_for :options do |field_option| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= render partial: "shopkeeper/products/variants/index/form/variant_box", :locals => {:form => field_option} %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

For aesthetic reason, every 3 `field_option` I want to be able to add a `<div class='row'>` so I don't break my grid system.

I know the method `in_groups_of(3, false)` which I use when I simply want to show data, but here we are in a special context of `form` therefore I'm out of solution ...

**What's the easiest way to achieve this ?**

Answer (score 0):

Because `fields_for` doesn't yield an index, the easiest way is probably to keep your own:

```
<% i = 0 %>
<div class='row'>
<%= f.fields_for :options do |field_option| %>
  <% if i % 3 == 0 && i > 0 %>
    </div><div class='row'>
  <% end %>
  <% i += 1 %>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <%= render partial: "shopkeeper/products/variants/index/form/variant_box", :locals => {:form => field_option} %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```